# Keep UIButton background change after click

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to make a button's background change from background1 to background2 when it's clicked and stay on background2 even when the app is restarted.

I've managed to do that, but when I restart the app the background is malformed ( the background2 is a transparent circle) its showing the circle, but the transparent part becomes white..

The button is a custom one.

Any ideas?
Thanks guys

Comment: Are you closing the app in the simulator then reopening using the play button? That restarts the process unless core data is involved. Test by pressing (ctrl + h) which will take you to the home of the simulator then open again. It should still be on your changed button.

Comment: I already done that and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem were in the `NSUserDefaults` saving process, I now use this :

```
  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(contactImage);
```

Instead of :

```
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(contactImage, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this will be useful to you..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BackgroundColor"];

   if (colorData != nil)
   {
      NSString *stringColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
      CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:stringColor];
      UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor];
      [self.btnNext setBackgroundColor:color];
  }


}
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
  [self.btnNext setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  CGColorRef colorRef = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  NSString *colorString = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:colorRef].stringRepresentation;
  NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:colorString];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"BackgroundColor"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

I have checked in ios 7 3.5 inch screen it is working..
but donot know on other deveices...